# VBA generate a code

Tags: excel, vba

there. I made this code that replaces a character for two number (e.g. 0 = 10; 1 = 11; 2 = 12; ...) and everything works fine except for the first element (the zero element). So, if I put "010a4" string on cell A1 and use my formula "=GENERATECODE(A1)", my expected return value is "1011102014" but I've got a "110111102014" string. So, only zero value occur this error and I can't figured out why. Any thoughts?

My code:

```
    Function GENERATECODE(Code As String)
    Dim A As String
    Dim B As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Const AccChars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Const RegChars = "1011121314151617181920212223242526272829303132333435363738394041424344454647484950515253545556575859606162636465666768697071"
    For i = 1 To Len(AccChars)
        A = Mid(AccChars, i, 1)
        B = Mid(RegChars, 2 * i - 1, 2)
        Code = Replace(Code, A, B)
    Next
    GENERATECODE = Code
End Function
```

Comment: Your problem is that your code first change each `0` to `10` then each `1` to `11`. So each `0` give you `10` then  `110`.

Comment: As Vincent pointed out, you're replacing char by char, thus after replacing 0 by 10, you replace again on same input. A solution would be to start from an empty string, and build it in the loop, using `&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to being incorrect, your current code is inefficient since it involves scanning over the code string multiple times instead of just once. Simply scan over the string once, gathering the substitutions into an array which is joined at the end:

```
Function GENERATECODE(Code As String) As String
    Dim codes As Variant
    Dim i As Long, n As Long
    Dim c As String
    n = Len(Code)
    ReDim codes(1 To n)
    For i = 1 To n
        c = Mid(Code, i, 1)
        Select Case c
            Case "0" To "9":
                codes(i) = "1" & c
            Case "a" To "z":
                codes(i) = Asc(c) - 77
            Case "A" To "Z":
                codes(i) = Asc(c) - 19
            Case Else:
                codes(i) = "??"
        End Select
    Next i
    GENERATECODE = Join(codes, "")
End Function
```

Example:

```
?generatecode("010a4")
1011102014
```

The point of the two offsets is that you want "a" to map to 20 and "A" to map to 46. Note `Asc("a") - 77 = 97 - 77` and `Asc("A") - 19 = 65-19 = 46`.

Comment: Worked fine and, apparently, it is more efficient than what I had done. Thank you for your elegant solution!!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your code first change each `0` to `10` then each `1` to `11`. So each `0` give you `10` then `110`.

If you want to keep the same kind of algorithm (which might not be a good choice), you need to change `AccChars` and `RegChars` so that a character is never replaced by a string that can give a character found later on the `AccChars` String. In your case just replace `Const AccChars = "012 ...` per `Const AccChars = "102 ...` and `Const RegChars = "101112 ...` per `Const RegChars = "111012 ...`

But it might be better to change your algorithm altogether. I would first suggest to not use in place editing of the string, but rather to use 2 Strings.

Comment: Wow... Thank you very much!!! Worked fine!!! I will explore another solution that will be more efficient (since my database is pretty huge), as you and others suggested. Again, thank you very much!!!